# Starting postdoc before getting PhD. Is that possible?

Tags: postdocs

I have already submitted the PhD thesis for examination. I have started to email potential supervisors yesterday to get information regarding postdoctoral positions in their departments. I am wondering whether it is possible to start postdoctorate while waiting for PhD viva.

Comment: A colleague actually started his Assistant Professorship before formally graduating. Threw the administration for a loop, and at the end of the day he was formally employed as a "research assistant" until graduation.

Comment: Depends on the country where you did your PhD and the country where you want to do your postdoc.

Comment: At some institutions you may be required to have fully completed your PhD before formally starting your postdoc.

Comment: In addition to country and institution requirements, it may depend on the funder also.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible. I and many others started a postdoc before officially obtaining the PhD. However, your chances may depend on country, postdoc position, and field. For example, in some countries before the official defense the PhD has already been examined by the committee and hence there may be more trust from a potential postdoc PI that you will not still be focusing on your PhD.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done; I did it, and know of a couple others who did; the most recent one was around 15 years ago but I have no reason to believe the rules would have radically changed. This was in the USA and Canada; I assume that specific institutions or countries may not allow this, and your Ph.D. supervisor may not approve of it either, perhaps because of concerns that the thesis work may fall by the wayside with the distraction of the post-doc.